# GIT --assume-unchanged batch files

Tags: php, git

I need to --assume-unchanged a whole project except for one folder, but i cant seem to find away to batch process all the files,

the only way i can think of doing it is with PHP, something like

```
$dir = getcwd();
$directory = new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir,\RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
    $iterator = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator($directory,\RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY);

    foreach ($iterator as $fileinfo) {
        shell_exec('--assume-unchanged '.$fileinfo);
    }
```

Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already added and commited the folder you don't mean to assume-unchanged, you can do

```
find . -type f -exec git update-index --assume-unchanged {} \;
```

it will still throw a lot of errors if you do it on the root, since it will try to assume-unchanged even the references inside .git folder.